# How to collect response of Android Apps in Json/Xml

Tags: java, android, json, xml, mobile

How can we see the **Response**(JSON/XML) of the **Android App** as we can see on Desktop for any web API by going to **developer tools**?

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox or Chrome on Android it's possible to view source by prefixing the URL in the address bar with "view-source:", i.e.

```
"view-source:http://google.com".
```

Answer (score 0):

It is probably best to remote debug your app/browser.
Remote debug live content on an Android device from your Windows, Mac, or Linux computer, with chrome-devtools.https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/?utm_source=dcc&utm_medium=redirect&utm_campaign=2016q3

Comment: Hey Jon, is it possible to debug apps which are not owned by me and collect their response to automate my own app?